# AddNew(), problems deleting this row

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, bindingsource

I have a DataGridView bound to a BindingSource. I then have a Button to add a new record:

```
Private Sub btnNew_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNew.Click
    _bsStaff.AddNew()
End Sub
```

This does create a new row, also following it with the "next new/blank" row. This works fine, except if I immediately press my Delete button to try and remove this newly added row:

```
Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    If MessageBox.Show("Delete staff member record?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, _
                       MessageBoxIcon.Question) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
        _bsStaff.RemoveCurrent()
    End If
End Sub
```

This removes the new row, but also the one before it!

I tried adding a line before RemoveCurrent, `_bsStaff.EndEdit()` and also `If _bsStaff.Position + 1 = _bsStaff.Count Then`, but the behaviour persists.

Could someone explain this behaviour and offer a solution?

---

**Added**: I thought I had it beat with this code, checking the row state:

```
Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click

    Dim state = CType(_bsStaff.Current, DataRowView).Row.RowState
    Select Case state
        Case DataRowState.Added
            _bsStaff.RemoveCurrent()
        Case DataRowState.Deleted
            MessageBox.Show("Row already deleted.", "Delete")
        Case DataRowState.Detached
            _bsStaff.CancelEdit()
        Case DataRowState.Modified
            If MessageBox.Show("Delete staff member record?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, _
                               MessageBoxIcon.Question) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
                _bsStaff.RemoveCurrent()
            End If
        Case DataRowState.Unchanged
            If _bsStaff.Position + 1 > _bsStaff.Count Then
                'do nothing, the new row
            ElseIf MessageBox.Show("Delete staff member record?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, _
                               MessageBoxIcon.Question) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
                _bsStaff.RemoveCurrent()
            End If
        Case Else
            'do nothing
    End Select
End Sub
```

However, looking at the screenshot,

[image]

when I click into the new row, and then click my button, it is in an Unchanged state, but it is the previous row that has the current record pointer (and that the Unchanged state probably refers to), it is this row that will be deleted.

Essentially, I think I need a way to detect that the new row has just been clicked into, but nothing has been typed, so that I can abandon the attempt to delete.

Comment: Make sure you dont have event code somewhere getting fired in the process.  What is the actual data repository?

Comment: `DefaultValuesNeeded` is used to select an item from a Department combobox. The data is SQL Server with two tables, Staff and Department. Ah yes, it is this code that affects it - but I still need this code to select a department. Without this code, and clicking into the new row and deleting, it also deletes the previous row. But maybe this is a slightly different issue?

Comment: Clicking into a new row immediately creates an increment value -1, -2, etc., which may be pertinent.

Comment: I have finally reproduced the problem...and a tentative solution BUT a) the datasource is a datatable?  That is, you create a table, then build a BindingSource from that?  Why?  The DGV more or less **is** a bindingsource: click top row == MoveFirst.  b) the DefaultValues needed should fire when the user clicks on that empty new row at the bottom.  Mine does not fire when a new row is added via the BS.

Comment: It was my understanding that we are encouraged to use them (BindingSources) and I've been happy with my use of them to this point, although I don't use them daily! I spotted also that bs.AddNew doesn't trigger the insertion of the default values, to resolve this I defined the Default Value with the definition of the DataTable. (I also wanted to have navigation buttons, but not to use the BindingNavigator.)

Comment: I think the main problem is that there are 2 ways to do anything and everything.  The user can start typing in the empty New Row at the bottom which fires the `DefaultValuesNeeded` event OR they can click `btnNew` which adds it a different way.  There ends up being ambiguity between the current row in the DGV and the BS

Comment: @Plutonix Yes, and the DGV, BindingSources and DataTables all have events and properties. My optimism was that BindingSource methods and events would handle most of the chores. I am keen to see your solution, tentative or not, I'm sure I can learn from your posting.

Comment: The issue is that `bs.AddNew()` does not cause `DefaultValuesNeeded` to fire and I dont know how you are affecting that.  If/when it does fire, you will have added **2 new rows**: one to the BS and another candidate-row to the DGV.  The new DGV "candidate" row automatically disappears on lost focus/exit unless the user enters something in one of the columns.

Comment: I got rid of that event and added a DefaultValue to the definition of the DataTable column. To get entirely consistent behaviour between AddNew and just clicking into the new row I can use `dgvStaff.CurrentCell = dgvStaff.Rows(dgvStaff.NewRowIndex).Cells(1)` and `dgvStaff.BeginEdit(True)`. The more DGV methods I add the more I see your point about the redundancy of the BindingSource with a DGV.

Comment: I think you have other event code which results in the weird  issue with the current record pointer.  I cant reproduce *that* using a simple DGV, BS and DT with no event code whatsoever.  I can get 2 new rows using the button and clicking into the dgv new row.  Since you can do all the navigation with DGV.CurrentCell, I'd get rid of the BindingSource.  If you like buttons, turn off the AllowUsersTo `Delete` and `AddRows` so there is just one way anything happens.

Comment: Other than button clicks I only use Load and FormClosing. Still, nevermind, I've spent enough time on it. When I move to do things properly, perhaps with Entity Framework, I'll have different issues :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime, and for comparison and comment (and criticism), I'll post my second, improved, solution here.

Here is my current full code block for the Delete method:

```
Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    If _bsStaff.Current Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub        'nothing to consider deleting
    End If
    Dim currentRow = CType(_bsStaff.Current, DataRowView).Row
    Dim sMemberMessage As String

    Dim state = currentRow.RowState
    Select Case state
        Case DataRowState.Added
            'newly added, just remove it
            _bsStaff.RemoveCurrent()
        Case DataRowState.Deleted
            MessageBox.Show("Row already deleted.", "Delete")
        Case DataRowState.Detached
            _bsStaff.CancelEdit()
        Case DataRowState.Modified, DataRowState.Unchanged
            If dgvStaff.SelectedCells.Count > 0 AndAlso _
                    dgvStaff.SelectedCells(0).RowIndex = dgvStaff.NewRowIndex Then
                'a new, blank, row, is attempted to be deleted
                '(the current row is the one before this)
                _bsStaff.CancelEdit()
                Exit Sub
            End If
            sMemberMessage = String.Format("Delete record ({0} {1} {2}) ?", _
                    _bsStaff.Current("StaffID"), _bsStaff.Current("FirstName"), _bsStaff.Current("LastName"))
            If MessageBox.Show(sMemberMessage, "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, _
                               MessageBoxIcon.Question) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
                _bsStaff.RemoveCurrent()
            End If
        Case Else
            'do nothing
    End Select
End Sub
```

The key component is here:

```
        Case DataRowState.Modified, DataRowState.Unchanged
            If dgvStaff.SelectedCells.Count > 0 AndAlso _
                    dgvStaff.SelectedCells(0).RowIndex = dgvStaff.NewRowIndex Then
                'a new, blank, row, is attempted to be deleted
                '(the current row is the one before this)
                _bsStaff.CancelEdit()
                Exit Sub
            End If
```

Looking at the screenshot in my question, although the current row is the one just above the new row, there is still a SelectedCell in the new row. With `dgvStaff.SelectedCells(0).RowIndex = dgvStaff.NewRowIndex` I am confirming that this cell is in the new (blank) row. Now this will **only** be the case if the user has clicked into this new row, so it is in an `Unchanged` state, and immediately pressed the Delete button, which is the exact situation I am trying to detect. If they had typed anything in this new row, then it would no longer be the new row (the test condition would not be met), nor would it be in an unchanged state. In these circumstances, the earlier cases would already have caused the row to be abandoned.

It is a little clumsy (I'm still hoping for an improvement upon this) but it is also a very specific circumstance that I am trying to capture.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post my current solution as a proposed, but reluctant, answer, in the hopes that it encourages someone to trounce me with a more professional solution.

I'm taking a pragmatic approach at the moment, explicitly telling the user which record they are about to delete:

```
Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    Dim currentRow = CType(_bsStaff.Current, DataRowView).Row
    Dim sMemberMessage As String

    Dim state = currentRow.RowState
    Select Case state
        Case DataRowState.Added
            _bsStaff.RemoveCurrent()
        Case DataRowState.Deleted
            MessageBox.Show("Row already deleted.", "Delete")
        Case DataRowState.Detached
            _bsStaff.CancelEdit()
        Case DataRowState.Modified, DataRowState.Unchanged
            sMemberMessage = String.Format("Delete record ({0} {1} {2}) ?", _
                    _bsStaff.Current("StaffID"), _bsStaff.Current("FirstName"), _bsStaff.Current("LastName"))
            If MessageBox.Show(sMemberMessage, "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, _
                               MessageBoxIcon.Question) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
                _bsStaff.RemoveCurrent()
            End If
        Case Else
            'do nothing
    End Select
End Sub
```

One would think that if someone has only just clicked into the new row that they would just click away from it, but because it immediately inserts an increment value and selects a department, one can see why they would be encouraged to click the Delete button.

(There must be some way of detecting that the row(s) are in this unusual, prone, state.)